# Dice rolling program which also counts and stores the result

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

Is there any room for improvement, in terms of simplicity and efficiency?

```
from random import randint

class Dice():

    def __init__(self):
        """Making a dice instance with 6 sides."""
        self.sides = 6

class Roller(Dice):

    def __init__(self,name,age):
        """Making a Dice Roller Instance"""
        super().__init__()
        #inhert sides attribute of a dice
        self.name = name
        self.age = str(age)

    def describe_roller(self):
        """Describe the information of the roller"""
        print('name: ' + self.name.title())
        print('age: ' + self.age)

    def roll_multiple(self,t):
        """Roll the dice multiple times and keep count in a dict"""
        count = {}
        one = 0
        two = 0
        three = 0
        four = 0
        five = 0
        six = 0
        for i in range(0,t):
            key = randint(1, self.sides)

            if key == 1:
                one += 1
                count["one"] = one
            elif key == 2:
                two += 1
                count["two"] = two
            elif key == 3:
                three += 1
                count["three"] = three
            elif key == 4:
                four += 1
                count["four"] = four
            elif key == 5:
                five += 1
                count["five"] = five
            elif key == 6:
                six += 1
                count["six"] = six
        print(count)


mike = Roller('mike',25)
mike.roll_multiple(6)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `Roller` should not inherit from `Dice`, as `Roller` represents a human. Humans being a sub-class of `Dice` is pretty unintuitive. Rather, `Roller` should have an attribute: `self.dice = Dice()`
2. There's no particular reason `Roller.age` should be of type `str`. I'd keep it as an `int` and only convert to `str` if you need its string-represantation.
3. f-Strings are a really convenient tool for creating strings containing variables / expressions. They also handle converting to `str` for you. Example: `print(f'age: {self.age}')`
4. You don't need the empty parantheses in `class Dice()`
5. You should put a space after the comma between arguments in a function call: `mike = Roller('mike',25)` becomes `mike = Roller('mike', 25)`
6. `roll_multiple` should be a method of `Dice` that can be called by the `Roller`. This is part of an intuitive API. Users (including yourself) will probably expect to roll the dice, not the human. If you need `Roller.roll_multiple`, I'd only make it a wrapper for `Dice.roll_multiple`.
7. `roll_multiple(self, t)`: `t` is not a particularly expressive variable name, something like `times` would be better for readability.
8. Adding type hints ([PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)) increases the readability of your code.
9. It's a convention in Python to name variables, whose values you don't actually use, `_`. So `for i in range(0,t):` becomes `for _ in range(t):`. Notice that you don't need to provide zero as the first argument as it's the default start for `range`.
10. Passing `sides` as a default argument to the constructor of `Dice` makes the class a whole lot more versatile.

---

**Algorithm**

Hardcoding values like

```
one = 0
two = 0
three = 0
...
```

should always raise a red flag when writing code. This is neither necessary nor recommended in most situations. You already laid the groundwork by putting `Dice.sides` in an attribute, now we need to use it. You also don't need to keep a seperate count of the occured values outside of the `dict`. I implemented it to exactly mirror your functionality (i.e. using string-representations as keys for the dict and only counting numbers that actually occured), inside of `class Dice`:

```
from random import randint
from collections import defaultdict
from num2words import num2words

...

def roll(self) -> int:
    return randint(1, self.sides)

def roll_multiple(self, times: int) -> dict:
    count = defaultdict(int)

    for _ in range(times):
        number = self.roll()
        key = num2words(number=number)
        count[key] += 1

    return dict(count)
```

[`num2words`](https://pypi.org/project/num2words/) is a third-party library, that needs to be installed first.

If having keys of type `int` is fine for your use case, I would recommend using them as they're way more usable for further calculations. You also don't necessarily need to cast to `dict`, as a `defaultdict` provides all the same basic functionality. It does make a difference when printing though. Here is the adjusted implementation:

```
def roll_multiple(self, times: int) -> defaultdict:
    count = defaultdict(int)

    for _ in range(times):
        key = self.roll()
        count[key] += 1

    return count
```

---

**Suggested code**

```
from random import randint
from collections import defaultdict


class Dice:
    def __init__(self, sides: int = 6):
        """Making a dice instance with a variable number of sides."""
        self.sides = sides

    def roll(self) -> int:
        """Returns the result of a single dice roll."""
        return randint(1, self.sides)

    def roll_multiple(self, times: int) -> defaultdict:
        """Provides the results of a variable number of dice rolls in a defaultdict."""
        count = defaultdict(int)

        for _ in range(times):
            key = self.roll()
            count[key] += 1

        return count


class Roller:
    def __init__(self, name: str, age: int) -> None:
        """Making a Dice Roller Instance"""
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

        self.dice = Dice()

    def describe_roller(self) -> None:
        """Describe the information of the roller"""
        print(f'name: {self.name.title()}')
        print(f'age: {self.age}')

    def roll_multiple(self, times: int) -> None:
        """Roll the dice multiple times and print the result"""
        print(self.dice.roll_multiple(times))
```

Comment: Overall agree. Drop the `__init__ -> None`; refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64933298/why-should-we-use-in-def-init-self-n-none

Comment: ...the above link actually argues in favour of an explicit `None`; https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/604 for more nuance

Comment: Interesting, thanks for providing the discussion links. I've also found the return type annotation for `__init__` rather unnecessary but I usually go full type hint for reviews (when recommending type hints at least).

Comment: Oh wow. This is the guidance and advice that I really needed. The result counting and storing part advice really hit the spot. Thank you for taking your time explaining and simplifying. I really really appreciate it. This really motivates me to code and learn more. Thank you so much.